# In a fantasy universe in which magic use is hereditary, what might be the odds of any one person being able to use or cast magic?

Tags: magic, genetics

I'm making a small text-based game in a world like that of Dragon Age or Harry Potter, and the fun of it is randomly generating NPC's, and changing behavior their behavior accordingly.

Would anyone have a ballpark estimate as to the proportional number of magic-users to others, or how the gene might manifest itself? (Dominant, recessive)

Comparison to an existing universe might be the Dragon Age Universe, or even Harry Potter. Ignoring the bias in both societies that could lead to abnormally high or low amounts of magic users.

The world I am working with will be conducive to larger amounts of magic users with variable levels of talent. The issue is having an unbalanced game world, or a world with too many or too few with magical talent. The distribution of talent among users would likely be similar to a bell curve.

I was thinking of something similar to 1 in 10 to 15 people have magical talent, and making the gene controlling possession of talent, a recessive gene.

Some areas of the world will have selective breeding, others will shun all showing magical talent. I'm concerned with general distribution for how many people out of 100 or 1000 might have magical talent.

I believe multiple genes would change small characteristics. How might I make sure I don't unbalance the world? Eventually I might integrate a combat system and want organized magic users to be strong, but not so much it changes world composition or the dynamics of fewer magic users to many without.

Comment: This is too broad in its current form. You'll need to narrow the scope down a little - what ideas have you already had, and what problems are you having with them?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I edited it for comparison to other universes.

Comment: That's still overly broad. We really need to see something that isn't just asking for ideas - instead, show us what progress you've already made and we may be able to develop it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Emrys. As it stands, this is considerably underdefined. Magic functions in whatever way you say it functions. You can use a [Punnett square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punnett_square) to get a general idea of the percentages.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Let me do some more editing.

Comment: That.....depends on a lot of factors. This is very much looking like idea generation right now. Genetics doesn't necessarily work 'nice and clean' like a Punnet Square would imply....and says nothing about the initial state or distribution, selective breeding, or anything else of the sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What percentage of the population has the "magic gene"?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36800/what-percentage-of-the-population-has-the-magic-gene)

Comment: With your latest edit...you basically answered your own question. "1 in 10" to "1 in 15" means there is either a 10% chance of having magic, or a 6.67% chance. If you use simple Punnet-style inheritance, you can twist the commonality of the Dominant allele and the Recessive allele in your population to anything you want. There is no rule that says the Dominant allele and recessive allele are equally common, or even strictly related. example: red hair is recessive, and only shows up in 1-2% of the population. Unless you are in Ireland or Scotland, in which case it's more like 10%.

Comment: @guildsbounty I'm asking for input on my estimate. Would this seem accurate or standard in comparison to similar fantasy universes?

Comment: Like others have said, when doing your edits, consider whether you want magic to work like eye color (multiple interacting genes), like blood type (multiple genes each contributing partially), like whether a cat reacts to catnip (single gene with uneven population distribution), or like what color a budgerigar is (single gene with even distribution).

Comment: @cobaltduck Thank you for reading my question and the edits, and for helping me clarify.

Comment: This question already have an answer in the question body / comments. If you want to ask about the genetic mechanics of dominant and recessive genes and their distribution in the population, you should head to [biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com)